# Checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my jquery

```
$('#hijue').change(function () {
  if($(this).prop(checked) == true) {
    $('#puta').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#puta').show();
  }
});
```

and this is my html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hijue" id="hijue" unchecked>
<div id="puta"></div>
```

This question has been posted by others before but I'm still stuck in retrieving the checkbox. Anybody please help

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Do you have a error what is your problem that you are having?

Comment: doesn't show any output @Haza

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `prop('checked')`.
Your current code uses the `checked` variable (which I guess you don't have).

If you open the console you should also see error regarding this.

```js
$('#hijue').change(function () {
  if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
    $('#puta').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#puta').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="hijue" id="hijue" unchecked>
<div id="puta">1234</div>
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't work for you" - did you run the snippet? What exactly your code look like? Because this snippet works...

Comment: can you help me solve another question please. i'm having a headache right now haha

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433263/how-to-update-db-instantly-based-on-checkbox-using-php-and-jquery?noredirect=1#comment68115317_40433263

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here: `.prop(checked)`, try `.is(':checked')` or `this.checked`

You may try `jQuery.toggle()`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#hijue").on('change', function() {
    $('#puta').toggle(!this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="hijue" id="hijue" unchecked>
<div id="puta">This is div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.is(':checked')` for very readable code:

```js
$('#hijue').change(function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#puta').hide();
  }
  else {
    $('#puta').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="hijue" id="hijue" unchecked>
<div id="puta">asdf</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#hijue').change(function () {
  $('#hijue').click(function() {
    $('#puta').hide();
  });
});
```