# How to update db instantly based on checkbox using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

jquery:

```
$("input[name='flag']").on('change', function() {
     event.preventDefault();
     var tablerow = $(this).closest('tr');
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var flagvalue;

     if($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
         tablerow.css({'background-color':'rgba(175,0,0,0.2)'});
         flagvalue = 1;
     }
     else {
         tablerow.css({'background-color':'rgba(175,0,0,0)'});
         flagvalue = 0;
     }
     alert(flagvalue);
     $.ajax({
         url: "../php/insert.php",
         method: "get",
         data: {"flagvalue":flagvalue,"id":id},
         dataType: "text"  
         success:function(data)  
         {  
            $('#ohmygod').html(data); //it doesnt echo anything from here :(
         }
     });
});
```

php:

```
$insertMessage = "";
$bendera = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'flagvalue', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$id = $_POST['id'];
if(!empty($bendera)) { //also doesn't work if change it to isset
    $insertMessage = "Reached the php part";
    $updateflag = "UPDATE sintok SET flag='$bendera' WHERE id='$id'"; 
    mysqli_query($connection, $updateflag); 
}
echo $insertMessage;
```

html:

```
<div id="ohmygod"></div>
```

include another php into html file:

```
<input value='.$row['id'].' type=checkbox name=flag id=flag '.$tick.'>
```

I have one checkbox which consist of two values, 0(unchecked) and 1(checked). From above code I don't see any changes except for the background-color of the row once the user has checked the checkbox button. But it didnt update the database. 
My question is, what is the correct syntax to update the data instantly from checkbox selection.

Comment: `flagvalue` != `flag` so `$bendera` is probably empty. You also are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries. Also if `0` is a valid value for `$bendera` to be you can't use `empty`, use `isset`.

Comment: I've already change the flagvalue. How to use parameterized queries?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. Did you correct the `empty` check?

Comment: Okay, then that should execute as is (I think). Not working still? The parameterized queries are to stop the potential SQL injection.

Comment: Is your db column id is `integer` ?

Comment: yes @MamdouhFreelancer. my id is an integer type

Comment: Try to change `id='$id'` to `id=$id` without quotes.

Comment: still not working Mamdouh

Comment: Do you sure about  `!empty($bendera)` is true try echo any thing after.

Comment: Update the question to your current code

Comment: @MamdouhFreelancer, oh god, it does not echo anything. let me update the question first

Comment: @nzrnfourtwenty, everything in your question is up to date? Does your `alert` works?

Comment: The alert from the jquery is worked. But the $insertMessage from php doesn't show anything

Comment: I've also change the path of file in jquery by putting them into the same folder. It seem like doesn't have anything to do with the file path problem

Comment: what is the html structure that  you have?

Comment: i'll edit the question

Comment: you only added a `php` block, not the entire html. where is the `#ohmygod` element in there?

Comment: Change your `success` function to: `success:function(data) { alert(data); $('#ohmygod').html(data); }`

Comment: done it, no result for the alert inside the success function

Comment: can you check my insert.php please. i think there is something wrong

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection, $updateflag) or die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Comment: yes it doesn't work

Comment: add `var_dump($bendera);` before the `if` statement.

Comment: still not achieving the target

Comment: I've found a solution!

Comment: I'm pointing to the wrong url because the jquery code is not inside the index.php, but it's included(by file) in the index.php.

Comment: Delete the question `I'm pointing to the wrong url` is a typo error. All previous comments still apply.